# Extract numerical values from Pandas (Python) object

Tags: python, list, pandas

I work with some database and use Pandas to make the analysis. The following entries should be arrays, but Pandas 'sees' them as objects. How to convert each row (entry) into an array or a list of numbers?

My task is to count a number of appearances of zeros '[0]' in this column (which should be 6).

```
df['q3']
Out[26]: 
7838        [1, 2, 3]
7790              [0]
7853     [1, 2, 3, 4]
7889           [1, 2]
7928        [1, 2, 3]
7847              [1]
7884              [1]
7826              [1]
22101             [1]
7784              [1]
7795              [1]
7743        [1, 3, 4]
7878     [1, 2, 3, 4]
7761              [0]
7771           [1, 3]
7901           [1, 3]
7873     [3, 2, 1, 4]
8424              [1]
7887              [0]
7969           [1, 2]
8020              [0]
7895              [0]
7834        [1, 2, 3]
7947              [1]
7822        [2, 3, 4]
7970              [0]
8124              [1]
7916           [1, 2]
Name: q3, dtype: object


In [27]: df['q3'].values
Out[27]: 
array([[u'1', u'2', u'3'], [u'0'], [u'1', u'2', u'3', u'4'], ..., [u'0'],
       [u'1'], [u'1', u'2']], dtype=object)
```

Comment: how about `q3.count(['0'])`?

Comment: @DanielSanchez, doesn't work! Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-60-59386d279e64>", line 1, in <module>
    df['q3'].count([u'0'])

  File "/Users/.../anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/pandas/core/series.py", line 1207, in count
    lev = self.index.levels[level]

AttributeError: 'Int64Index' object has no attribute 'levels'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seem you can use:

```
from  itertools import chain
from collections import Counter

#convert values to ints
df.q3 = df.q3.apply(lambda x: [int(y) for y in x])

#flat columns to list
a = list(chain.from_iterable(df.q3))
#print (a)

#count all ints
b = Counter(a)
print (b)
Counter({1: 21, 2: 10, 3: 10, 0: 6, 4: 5})

print (b[0])
6
```

Answer (score 0):

you maybe can try iterate over using q3.idxmin(),
then check if the value from the returned index is different than 0.

By the way, to follow on Daniel Sanchez answer:
try counting 0 like this:
count(0)

Comment: in theory yes, but it doesn't work in practice (I don't know why BTW).

Comment: try not to search for a string ' ' when using count?

Answer (score 0):

Ensure the q3 series dtype is an object (string), then count the slice.

This will work when initial data arrays contain string or integer elements.

```
sq3 = df.q3.astype(str)
np.where((sq3.values == '[0]') | (sq3.values == "['0']"))[0].size
```